# Best way to store PHP session from iPhone website when added to homescreen?

Tags: php, iphone, session

I have a website/webapp where you can login and it starts a php session.
If a user adds the site to their homescreen they have to log in every time they start the app.
I know this is a well know issue but I can't find a good and complete solution. I want the users to be able to open the app and if they have been logged in before they should become logged in from start.

I have read a bit about local storage which seems to maybe be something but I'm worried about the security issues of storing something locally. I don't want an user to pose as another. Maybe you can encrypt the stored values somehow?

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems obvious.... is there a reason you haven't tried Cookies?

Store the session data in a database on your server, with some sort of hash, then simply pass that hash to the user in a cookie so they can retrieve it when they get back to your site.

Comment: Is it the best way to do this? How do I store a session in a cookie so that the user is already logged in when they return?

Comment: Ops misread that one :P I saw the update thx. I will try it out!